# How do I create a custom Semantic Token for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, semantics, vs-color-theme-editor

I'm creating a color theme and I found out that the only way to target function parameters with italic is by using semantic highlight. The problem is that since semantic highlight overrides some settings, I lost the ability to target `support.function.console` - the "log" of console.log, for instance.

`.log` is a `member.defaultLibrary`, but if I target that by semantic, some other things would also be styled with the same color. That wouldn't be bad if `member.defaultLibrary` wasn't so inconsistent, some things you would expect to be styled, is not, which leads to inconsistency, which is certainly not desirable.

`querySelector()` is styled by `member.defaultLibrary` but not `querySelectorAll()`, for instance. I also tried to not use anything that can be overridden by semantics but then, it creates too many exceptions and some functions and methods would be let without any style, which is much worse.

I've tried [Semantic Token Classification](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-token-classification) and tried to add a custom semantic token to the `package.json` file of the extension but I don't know how to "wire" that up:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "semanticTokenTypes": [
      {
        "id": "consoleSupport",
        "description": "console support"
      }
    ],
    "semanticTokenScopes": [
      {
        "scopes": {
          "consoleSupport": ["support.function.console"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When using development host, it does recognize the "new" `consoleSupport` when I try to add to "semanticTokenColors", it suggests the auto-complete, so I'm probably half-way there but I don't know how to actually create the new token and how to make it work.